# Duplicated content from Firebase query after updating it

Tags: swift2, firebase

I'm doing an application about shared notes using Swift and Firebase.

Once I load the view where the notes are displayed, a tableview gets filled with the notes information on each row:

[image]

To do so, first I do a query to find the IDs of the notes the user follows and then from each ID I get the note information with another query.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    listOfNotes.removeAll()

    //QUERY NOTES IDs IN USER

    let userRef = ref.childByAppendingPath("users/" + sessionUserID + "/participating")

    userRef.queryOrderedByValue().observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in

        //Saving note ID
        let savingNoteID = snapshot.key

        let notesDetailsRef = ref.childByAppendingPath("notes/" + savingNoteID + "/details")

        self.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"

        notesDetailsRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot2 in

            let fireNoteTitle = snapshot2.value.objectForKey("noteTitle")! as! String
            let fireNoteText = snapshot2.value.objectForKey("noteText")! as! String
            let fireNoteUpdatedToConvert = snapshot2.value.objectForKey("noteUpdate")! as! String
            let fireNoteUpdatedConverted = self.dateFormatter.dateFromString(fireNoteUpdatedToConvert)

            let newNote = NoteInfo(noteID: savingNoteID as String, noteTitle: fireNoteTitle , noteUsers: "Users" as String, noteText: fireNoteText as String, noteUpdated: fireNoteUpdatedConverted!)

            listOfNotes.append(newNote)
            self.tableNotes.reloadData()

        })
    })
}
```

Then, selecting a row I segue to a new VC to see the info from the note.

Later, when I'm leaving the note view to go back to the list, in the `viewWillDisappear`, I update the noteinfo:

```
ref.updateChildValues([
        "notes/" + sessionNoteID + "/details/noteText": texto,
        "notes/" + sessionNoteID + "/details/noteTitle": title,
        "notes/" + sessionNoteID + "/details/noteCreator" : fireNoteCreator,
        "notes/" + sessionNoteID + "/details/noteCreation" : fireNoteCreation,
        "notes/" + sessionNoteID + "/details/noteUpdate" : String(NSDate())])
```

and the previously selected note appears duplicated:
(Do you know why is this happening? If I remove the update or if I just load the NoteID instead of the details it works perfectly.)

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: hi victor,  may i know how you overcome this?

Comment: yeah I did. Is because of how (.Value) works

Comment: How exactly did you solve this, give a snippet please

Comment: @SimpiMind I was not understanding well the Firebase API call behaviour. There was no need to refresh or add the last item when going back to the view because it was doing it automatically. That's why it was duplicated. If you go to their manuals now is easier to understand

Comment: I still don't get it, cus am having the same issue in two instances of my app presently, is there a place to message you directly, probably you can help me out?

Comment: check my Twitter user on my profile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's doesn't appear to be duplicated, it appears another note was added to the array; the timestamp is different.

When you added an observer to the node (.Value), it is triggered once with the initial data and again every time the data changes.

In this case, if you update the data, the block will be called and a 'new' note will be added with the new time stamp.

Comment: i got the same problem. Do you have any idea how to deal with it?  if i have to listening on the data changes?

Comment: @vzhen So the issue is that you are duplicating effort. 1) You append the object to the array and when data is written to the Firebase node, that also reads in the data and appends it to the array, so you end up with duplicate data. So best bet is one or there other: either stop observing the node while you are writing data out, or write the data out and let the array populate from those writes.

Comment: thanks for reply, what do you meant by `let the array populate from those writes` ?  Are you mean i have to use .slice() or concat() to populate the array before render to view?

Comment: No. Remember that when you write to a node that's being observed, that data is sent to your app. So if, in one section of your app you write to a node and that node is being observed, the data you just wrote would then be sent to the app. In this case, you could use that data to populate the array instead of array.append(data) within the write function. If you do both the append as well as adding the data to the array within the observer block, then the data is duplicated. So, do one or there other.

Comment: i found this article. Is this what you meant?
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/05/handling-synchronized-arrays-with-real.html

Comment: @vzhen Kinda... What I meant is what was posted in my answer. If you write data to a node that's being observed, within that .Value block you will receive the data that was added. If you are adding data to an array within that block, the data that was added will be appended to the array.  If you are also appending data to an array before writing the data, that data will be duplicated. Once when it's appended before the write and a second time when the observer block is triggered from Firebase by new data being written.

Comment: Right, i understand what you mean. My question is what is the recommended way to solve this.

Comment: @vzhen As I mentioned above a couple of times either a) stop observing the node you are writing to and populate the array from code in the block you write the data from or b) don't populate the array from the block you write data from and let the observer populate the array once the data is written.